# Build and run .NET projet without Visual Studio

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-2015, msbuild

We have a website project written in .NET (not Core so I can't use dotnet CLI): how is it possible to build and run the solution without using VS2015 "play button" from command line/powershell?

The equivalent than pressing on this button:

[image: Run in Google Chrome]

The desired actions:

- Build
- Run in Google Chrome (which "build" the web project on IIS Express)
- Let the instance run until I kill it

Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

> how is it possible to build and run the solution without using VS2015 "play button" from command line/powershell?

We could use MSBuild command line to build the solution without using Visual Studio 2015. But as far as I know, we could not run the **website project** in Google Chrome without using VS2015 from command line/powershell.